# react native iOS native video player doesn't play second time after device lock-unlock

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a react-native application which uses iOS native video player, and we do offline playback, the first time the user play the video it works normally, but if the user locks his device, then unlock it, the video will not play and will not show anything but a black screen.
and, it works fine with online streaming, no matter how many times the user lock/unlock his device, the online video will still pla normally each time.

what could be the problem here ? since I cannot see any warning, or any errors happening.

Comment: I'm thinking of how can I remove the player completely from memory ?